# Twitter API, finding logged-in user

Tags: oauth, twitter

I log into my Twitter account. Then I visit [this twitter app website](http://who.unfollowed.me/). I click sign-in with Twitter link, I am redirected to Twitter authorization page, I give auth. Then I see member page of app website. Then I check authed Applications from my Twitter account: https://twitter.com/settings/applications

I see that I authed that application. Then I remove all cookies of app website. But I don't logout from Twitter website. I revisit app website and click Sign-in with twitter.

Without Auth confirmation I am redirected to members page. How can it be?

I understand that they save my auth tokens inside their database and use to verify credentials. But without cookie etc. how can they know that I'm that Twitter user?

Is it possible to know that user logged in to Twitter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem can be solved when "authenticating" is used rather then "authorization".
Authorization needs permission everytime user sign-ins, authentication needs permisson if user didn't give permission previously or he/she revoked the permission.

That is called as transparent login.

Note: Authentication doesn't include DM access.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/implementing-sign-twitter